# QuestPDF: Disappearing First Table when Adding Second Table

Tags: c#, .net

### Issue: Disappearing First Table when Adding Second Table

**Description:** I'm currently working on a C# application that uses QuestPDF to generate PDF documents. In my code, I have a first table inside a page, and I want to add a second table after the first table in the same page. However, when I add the second table, the first table seems to disappear in the generated PDF. I want to keep both tables visible on the same page.

Here's how I structured my code:

```cs
var document = Document.Create(container =>
{
    container.Page(page =>
    {
        // ... Page setup and styling ...

        page.Content().Table(table =>
        {
            // First table content ...
        });

        // Adding a second table, but it causes the first table to disappear
        page.Content().Table(newTable =>
        {
            // Second table content ...
        });
    });
});
```

My full code if it helps:

```cs
using QuestPDF.Fluent;
using QuestPDF.Helpers;
using QuestPDF.Infrastructure;
using QuestPDF.Previewer;

namespace HTMLToPDFWithQuestPDF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var document = Document.Create(container =>
            {
            container.Page(page =>
            {
            page.Size(PageSizes.Letter);
            page.Margin(1, Unit.Centimetre);
            page.PageColor(Colors.White);
            page.DefaultTextStyle(x => x.FontSize(10));
            page.DefaultTextStyle(x => x.FontFamily(Fonts.Calibri));

            page.Header()
                .AlignRight()
                .Text("Appendix 1")
                .FontFamily("Arial")
                .FontSize(10)
                .LineHeight(1.5f)
                .FontColor(Colors.Green.Lighten1);

            page.Content().Table(table =>
            {
                table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
                {
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                });

                // by using custom 'Element' method, we can reuse visual configuration
                table.Cell()
                .ColumnSpan(4)
                .Row(1)
                .Column(1)
                .Element(Block)
                .Text("PURCHASE ORDER")
                .Bold()
                .FontSize(20);

                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(2).Column(1).Element(Block);
                table.Cell()
                .ColumnSpan(4)
                .Row(2)
                .Column(1)
                .Padding(5)
                .Text(
                    "Barangay: " +
                    "\n" +
                    "Tel. No:"
                    )
                .LineHeight(1f)
                .FontSize(10);

                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(2).Column(3).Element(Block);
                table.Cell()
                .ColumnSpan(2)
                .Row(2)
                .Column(3)
                .Padding(5)
                .Text(
                    "City Municipality: " +
                    "\n" +
                    "Province: "
                    )
                .LineHeight(1f)
                .FontSize(10);

                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(3).Column(1).Element(Block);
                table.Cell()
                .ColumnSpan(2)
                .Row(3)
                .Column(1)
                .Padding(5)
                .Text(
                    "Supplier: " +
                    "\n" +
                    "Address: "
                    )
                .LineHeight(1f)
                .FontSize(10);

                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(3).Column(3).Element(Block);
                table.Cell()
                .ColumnSpan(2)
                .Row(3)
                .Column(3)
                .Padding(5)
                .Text(
                    "P.O. No.: " +
                    "\n" +
                    "Date: "
                    )
                .LineHeight(1f)
                .FontSize(10);

                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(4).Column(1).Element(Block);
                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(4).Column(1)
                .Padding(5)
                .Text(
                    "TIN:")
                .FontSize(10);

                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(4).Column(3).Element(Block);
                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(4).Column(3)
                .Padding(5)
                .Text(
                    "Mode of Procurement:" +
                    "\n" +
                    "Bidding Negotiated Over the Counter")
                .FontSize(10);

                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(4).Row(5).Column(1).Element(Block);
                table.Cell()
               .ColumnSpan(4)
               .Row(5)
               .Column(1)
               .Padding(5)
               .Text(
                    "Gentlemen:" +
                    "\n" +
                    "           Please deliver to this Office the following articles subject to the terms and conditions contained herein.")
               .FontSize(10);

                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(6).Column(1).Element(Block);
                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(6).Column(1)
                .Padding(5)
                .Text(
                    "Place of Delivery: " +
                    "\n" +
                    "Date of Delivery: "
                    )
                .LineHeight(1)
                .FontSize(10);

                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(6).Column(3).Element(Block);
                table.Cell().ColumnSpan(2).Row(6).Column(3)
                .Padding(5)
                .Text(
                    "Delivery Term: " +
                    "\n" +
                    "Payment Term: "
                    )
                .LineHeight(1)
                .FontSize(10);

            });

            // Second table (added after the first table)
            page.Content().Table(newTable =>
            {
                newTable.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
                {
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                    columns.RelativeColumn();
                });

                newTable.Cell()
                    .ColumnSpan(3)
                    .Row(1)
                    .Column(1)
                    .Element(Block)
                    .Text("Second Table Content")
                    .Bold()
                    .FontSize(16);
            });

            page.Footer()
            .AlignCenter()
            .Text(x =>
            {
                x.Span("Page ");
                x.CurrentPageNumber();
            });

            });
            });

            document.ShowInPreviewer();

        }
        static IContainer Block(IContainer container)
        {
            return container
                .Border(0.5f)
                .ShowOnce()
                .MinWidth(50)
                .MinHeight(25)
                .AlignCenter()
                .AlignMiddle();
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue:** After adding the second table, the first table no longer appears in the generated PDF. I would like to know how I can keep both tables visible on the same page.

**Questions:**

1. What is the reason for the first table disappearing when I add the second table?
2. How can I modify my code to ensure that both tables are displayed on the same page in the generated PDF?

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```cs
page.Content = // content
page.Content = // other content (which overrides the first)
```

I used a container element:

```cs
page.Content().Column(c =>
{
  c.Item().Table(...) // first table
  c.Item().Table(...) // second table
});
```

This is because Content() can only be assigned once.

Comment: @Nikolay Krastev this is my solution to my problem. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess will be you are overwriting it. I'm also stuck at this problem at the moment, the only idea that is in my mind is to add two additional tables in the first cells of the main one... which probably is awful idea.

Comment: Yes. I agree. However, I think it's the best way to do it, which in this case, I used a container element for each table since Content() can only be assigned once.